# How to pass the values from activity to another activity

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

As I'm learning Kotlin for Android development, I'm now trying the basic programs like hello world and how to navigate from one activity to another activity, there is no issue with this.

When I move from one activity to another, it works fine, but I do not know how to pass the values between the activities.

I tried to set the values in one activity and retrieved them in another activity it does not work.

Please see the code snippet below

This is my main activity where I take the username and password from edit text and setting to the intent:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    val userName = null
    val password = null
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        button.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity,SecondActivity::class.java);
            var userName = username.textø
            var password = password_field.text
            intent.putExtra("Username", userName)
            intent.putExtra("Password", password)
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my second activity where I have to receive values from the main activity

```
class SecondActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second)
        var strUser: String = intent.getStringExtra("Username")
        var strPassword: String = intent.getStringExtra("Password")
        user_name.setText("Seelan")
        passwor_print.setText("Seelan")
    }
}
```

Please guide me on how to do this, whether I have some other way to do this in Kotlin if not by intent.

Comment: Kotlin should make it simpler. We should be able to pass data like Parameters in Activity. I am pretty sure it is not hard to achieve.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Send value from HomeActivity

```
val intent = Intent(this@HomeActivity, ProfileActivity::class.java)
intent.putExtra("Username", "John Doe")

startActivity(intent)
```

Get values in `ProfileActivity`

```
val profileName = intent.getStringExtra("Username")
```

Comment: Logic question: If we create **intent** in Activity #1, how can we access it without declaring at activity #2?

Comment: This activity#2 intent is getIntent() which is intent(getIntent) in kotlin

Comment: I'm not super dev. for Android, but I've paste your lines of code and it doesn't work)

Answer (score 12):

In Kotlin, you can pass the data simply by using the Intents. You can directly put your data in intent or you can write those data in bundle and send that bundle to another activity using the intent.

```
val intent = Intent(this@HomeActivity, ProfileActivity::class.java);
intent.putExtra("profileName", "John Doe")
var b = Bundle()
b.putBoolean("isActive", true)
intent.putExtras(b)
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 11):

I'm on mobile, you must test by yourself.

Try to make a `CharSequence` to a `String` in `MainActivity` , you have put a `CharSequence` rather than a `String`, for example:

```
var userName = username.text.toString()
var password = password_field.text.toString()
```

Comment: @Jeyaseelan Not at all.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use the intents and bundle to send data from one activity to another activity.

```
val intent = Intent(this@OneActivity,TwoActivity::class.java);
intent.putExtra("username", userName)
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    //On Click on Button 

    var but = findViewById<Button>(R.id.buttionActivity_two) as Button

            but.setOnClickListener {
    //Define intent 
                var intent = Intent(applicationContext,MainActivity::class.java)
// Here "first" is key and 123 is value                
intent.putExtra("first",123)
                startActivity(intent)

            }

        }

// If Get In Into Other Activity
var Intent1: Intent
Intent1= getIntent()
//Here first is key and 0 is default value
      var obj :Int  =  Intent1.getIntExtra("first",0);
      Log.d("mytag","VAlue is==>"+obj)
```

Answer (score 2):

first you should do this,

```
var userName = username.text.toString()
var password = password_field.text.toString()
```

Add Anko dependency.

```
 implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko:0.10.4"
```

information passing inside `MainActivity()` is like

```
startActivity<SecondActivity>("Username" to userName,"Password" to password )
```

get information from `SecondActivity()` is,

```
val profileName=intent.getStringExtra("Username")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just access the value without using extras or intent. Simply use companion object in MainActivity:

```
    companion object{
        val userName: String = String()
        val password: String = String()
    }
```

In SecondActivity:

```
    var strUser: String = MainActivity.username
    var strPassword: String = MainActivity.password
```

And you can access the values from multiple activities easily.

Comment: **Kotlin:** *Unresolved reference: companion*

Answer (score 0):

```
Send data  


    val Name=findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editTextTextPersonName)  
    val Name2=findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editTextTextPersonName2)  
    val name=Name.text.toString()  
    val age=Name2.text.toString()  
    val intent1=Intent(this,Second::class.java).also {  
    it.putExtra("Username",name)  
    it.putExtra("Age",age)  
    startActivity(it);   
    }
```

Receive data

```
val name=intent.getStringExtra ("Username")
val age = intent.getStringExtra("Age")
val textView5=findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView).apply {
text= "Name = $name"
}
val textView6=findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView2).apply {
text= "Age = $age"
}
```