# android kotlin - start activity and getting data from intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, kotlin

I want to simply start an activity and send some data to my second activity , this is my code :

Activiy main:

```
 val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, Cards::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("title", catItem.name)
            intent.putExtra("catId", catItem.id)
            startActivity(intent)
```

catItem is not null and every item in it has value , i've debugged and I'm sure about it .

the second activity that I need to get data :

```
 val bl:Bundle=intent.extras
    catId=bl.getString("catId")
    title=bl.getString("title")
```

it crashes on the second line :

```
 bl.getString("catId") must not be null
```

I debugged and the bundle is completely empty .

what is wrong with this code ?

Comment: Because you are passing data into Intent but getting its using Bundle. There is no need to get data using bundle. Just call intent.getStringExtra("catId") if catId is string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass the values from activity to another activity in kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45157567/how-to-pass-the-values-from-activity-to-another-activity-in-kotlin)

Answer (score 3):

To retrieve data on second activity you just need to access directly intent's extra data as follows:

```
val catId = intent.getStringExtra("catId")
```

Also, be sure that "catId" type is String (an ID usually is an Integer or Long), because if it is not an String, you will get the same error.

Answer (score 2):

According to your activity start code(just copy of your code):

```
val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, Cards::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("title", catItem.name)
            intent.putExtra("catId", catItem.id)
            startActivity(intent)
```

In Cards Activity `onCreate` method:

if they are

**Required:**

```
val arguments = requireNotNull(intent?.extras){"There should be parameters or your more meaningful message."} 

with(arguments){
          catId = getString("catId")
          title = getString("title")
         }
```

**Not Required:**

```
catId = intent?.extras?.getString("catId").orEmpty()
title= intent?.extras?.getString("title").orEmpty()
```

or

```
catId = intent?.extras?.getString("catId","default Cat").orEmpty()
title= intent?.extras?.getString("title","default Title").orEmpty()
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `getExtra` to `getStringExtra`

```
bl.getStringExtra("catId")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in your code catItem.id is null, because of it catId is null, which causes of crash.

Please try below code to overcome the crash:

```
var bundle :Bundle ?=intent.extras
var title = bundle!!.getString("title")
var catId = bundle!!.getString("catId")
```

I hope its work for you.

Comment: !! are not recommended to use. Because we use kotlin to get rid of NullPointer Exceptions.