# How to send value in an other activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, kotlin

Hello and sorry for my english i'm french. I'm learning Android development and i try to send int value in an other activity. I have declared an int variable to 0 and when i press a button the variable go to 1 on other value for each buttons. I know how to create an intent but how can i make it get the value of my button. Thanks.

Comment: check this answer:
<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45157567/how-to-pass-the-values-from-activity-to-another-activity-in-kotlin>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass data between Activities in Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple.

On the sending side

`int intValue` = get value from edit text or button

use `Intent.putExtra` to set value

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(test1.this, test2.class);
myIntent.putExtra("yourname", intValue);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

On the receiver side

use `Intent.getIntExtra` to get value

```
Intent mIntent = getIntent();
 int intValue = mIntent.getIntExtra("yourname", 0);
```

`intValue` is your value

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use putExtra on your intent to add the int value you want to send to the next activity like so:

```
val intent = Intent(this, NextActivity::class.java)
intent.putExtra("samplevalue", 1)
startActivity(intent)
```

Then on that activity (NextActivity), you will use the code below to retrieve the value.

```
val buttonValue:Int = intent.getIntExtra("samplevalue", 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

first activity

```
        Intent intent =new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("value", yourValue);
        startActivity(intent);
```

second Activity

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.intent);

        Intent iin = getIntent();
        Bundle bundle = iin.getExtras();

        if(bundle != null)
        {
            String name = (String) bundle.get("name");

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a Intent for your target Activity then use [putExtra](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String,%20int)) method to put data in Intent.

```
  val intent = Intent(context, TargetActivity::class.java)
  intent.putExtra("some_value", value)
```

Then start your Activity

```
startActivity(intent)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the parameters by putting key-value pairs into the intent bundle:

```
// ActivityOne.java
public void launch() {
  // first parameter is the context, second is the class of the activity to launch
  Intent i = new Intent(ActivityOne.this, ActivityTwo.class);
  // put "extras" into the bundle for access in the second activity
  i.putExtra("username", "foobar"); 
  i.putExtra("in_reply_to", "george"); 
  i.putExtra("code", 400);
  // brings up the second activity
  startActivity(i); 
}
```

Once you have added data into the bundle, you can easily access that data within the launched activity:

```
// ActivityTwo.java (subactivity) can access any extras passed in
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   String username = getIntent().getStringExtra("username");
   String inReplyTo = getIntent().getStringExtra("in_reply_to");
   int code = getIntent().getIntExtra("code", 0);
}
```

more information check [this](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-Intents-to-Create-Flows)