# How can I redirect from an activity to another activity after some delays?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-activity

I'm a beginner to Kotlin language. I have trouble redirection to another activity after for example 4 seconds. I know how to do it in Java but I have no idea about Kotlin. I use android studio version 2019.

I tried android studio's converter (Java to Kotlin)
I couldn't find an answer which lead me to an answer that could redirect me from an activity to another by DELAY. I'm not asking about other ways of redirecting I'm asking exactly about delay. I mean how to go to another page in an android program not clicking any button or something.

edit (Sep 13):
unfortunately I'm still struggling with the problem. I tried to use this code but It doesn't work. Can you please tell me what is the problem:
MainActivity.kt:

```
package com.rearaa.weading
import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Handler

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
}
val handler = Handler()
val runnable = Runnable {
    val i = Intent(this@MainActivity, MenuPage::class.java)
    startActivity(i)
}
handler.postDelayed(runnable, 4000)

}
```

In above code I want to redirect from MainActivity to MenuPage.

Comment: If you used the Android Studio auto converter. Then what didn't work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass the values from activity to another activity in kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45157567/how-to-pass-the-values-from-activity-to-another-activity-in-kotlin)

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: there are basically 2 different tasks: 1) run code after some delay; 2) redirect to another activity. So which one is a problem?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I don't know! maybe conversion is not fully correct bcz I get some erros.

Comment: @RaguSwaminathan no it's not. there is no answer there for my "delay" question.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko the second I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This how you can do it in android using Kotlin

```
private lateinit var mHandler: Handler
private lateinit var mRunnable: Runnable
```

Function :

```
private fun startMainActivity() {


    mRunnable = Runnable {
        startActivity(Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java))
        finish()
    }

    mHandler = Handler()

    mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 4000)
}
```

Remove Callbacks:

```
override fun onStop() {
    super.onStop()
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable)
}
```

Comment: MainActivity is the second page?

Comment: Yes, it is the second activity.

Comment: sorry, where should I use the function?

Comment: You should write this function in the activity.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `Handler().postDelayed()`.

For example:

```
Handler().postDelayed({
      startActivity(Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java))
    }, 4000); //4 Seconds
```

Comment: I get this error: function declaration must have a name

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
   val r = Runnable {
         //start your activity here
    }
    Handler().postDelayed(r, 3000)
```

3000 is delay time , you can change it to any value that you want.

Answer (score 1):

There are so many ways one of them is

```
 private lateinit var handler: Handler
```

Here is the function

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        handler = Handler()

        handler.postDelayed(object : Runnable {
            override fun run() {


                startActivity(
                    Intent(
                        this@SplashActivity,
                          LoginActivity::class.java
                    )
                )

                finish()


            }
        }, timeDelay)


    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Schedule](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.concurrent/java.util.-timer/schedule.html)

```
inline fun Timer.schedule(
    delay: Long, 
    crossinline action: TimerTask.() -> Unit
): TimerTask (source)
```

found it here: http://jamie.mccrindle.org/2013/02/exploring-kotlin-standard-library-part-3.html)
    import java.util.Timer
    import kotlin.concurrent.schedule

```
Timer("SettingUp", false).schedule(500) { 
   doSomething()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

shortest sample:

```
        Handler().postDelayed({ startActivity(yourIntent()) }, 4000L)
```

Answer (score 1):

Redirect to another activity(FirstActivity) from MainActivity after 4 second:

```
val handler = Handler()
        val runnable = Runnable {
            val i = Intent(this@MainActivity, FirstActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(i)
        }
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 4000)
```

Comment: I get the error "Expecting member declaration". Then what should I do?